# Jest - testing redux actions

Tags: testing, mocking, redux, action, jestjs

I'm trying to test my app's redux actions using Jest. I've looked at the testing site @ redux.js.org and other forums posts but I can't see why I'm getting the error I am, I think I'm not getting how the mocking works.

My action is in index.js:

```
export const setResponse = (res) => {
    return {
        type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED',
        payload: res
    }
};
```

My test is actions.test.js:

```
import * as actions from '../src/client/scripts/actions/index'

describe('actions', () => {
  it('should create an action to receive a response', () => {
    const payload = {response: 'solr_json'};
    const expectedAction = {
      type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED',
      payload
    }
    expect(actions.setResponse(payload)).toEqual(expectedAction)
  })
});
```

I got the error 'Expected undefined to equal Object...' soI thought actions.setResponse didn't exist, so I printed out actions.setResponse and it looks like this:

```
{ [Function: setResponse]
  _isMockFunction: true,
  getMockImplementation: [Function],
  mock: { calls: [], instances: [] },
  mockClear: [Function],
  mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
  mockReturnValue: [Function],
  mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
  mockImpl: [Function],
  mockImplementation: [Function],
  mockReturnThis: [Function] }
```

So it seems the function is there, how do I actually call the function inside the Jest test? Even if I change

```
export const setResponse = (res) =>
```

to

```
export function setResponse(res)
```

(so it's the same format of the redux.js.org tutorial) I get the same error. For reference this is the jest part of my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      ".test.js"
    ],
    "testPathDirs": [
      "__tests__"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react",
      "node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
      "node_modules/react-dom"
    ]
  }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that the module you want to test is mocked, cause you use `unmockedModulePathPatterns`. From the docs:

> An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all
>   modules before the module loader will automatically return a mock for
>   them. If a module's path matches any of the patterns in this list, it
>   will **not** be automatically mocked by the module loader.

I would guess that if you remove this line the module is not automatically mocked. Normally its easier to mock the stuff that you want to mocked directly in your test using `jest.mock`. Or you add your source folder to the list of `unmockedModulePathPatterns`.

Comment: I tried both of those and it's still being mocked :(

Comment: Which version of Jest do you use? This are my settings and I never have any thing mocked automatically: `"jest": { "testRegex":"./tests/.*/.*\\.spec\\.js$", "rootDir": "." }`

Comment: I'm using v13.2.3 also another weird thing happens, even if I just run it normally it acts like I'm running it in 'watch' mode, i.e. it only runs the tests when I do something like move the file, or edit the file or whatever :/

Comment: Oh wow, npm installed quite an old one by default. I should've checked. I updated and everything's working fine now. Thanks! :)